# flutter get when to use GetX<Controller>, GetBuilder<Controller> or Obx()

Tags: flutter, flutter-get

As the title reads, there are a couple of ways to update state. When should I choose one over another?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65405741/how-to-flutter-getx-binds-obs-to-widget This link has answer of your question

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There's no hard rules about this, but here's how I try to decide:

#### Obx

- when my controller is **already registered** elsewhere and I want
- minimal code/noise
- a reactive widget

#### GetX

- when my controller *isn't* yet registered or
- I want to be very explicit/obvious which controller is being used or
- I need to run some `initState` calls during creation and I want
- a reactive widget

#### GetBuilder

- I want to manually decide when a widget rebuilds
- I have several state variables that make sense to refresh together as a group

#### Notes

Under the hood, both Obx and GetX use streams, subscribing to controller observable variables change streams to know when to reactively rebuild.

GetBuilder does not.

GetX and GetBuilder both extend `StatefulWidget`