# Moving from Provider to GetX and cannot Get.find the correct Controller

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-getx

I'm trying to move from `Provider` to `GetX` and am stuck on how `GetX.find()` works.

We have a `restaurant` app with a few `table`s. Below is the narrowed down view of my old `Provider` code showing just the `staff` table and `VIP` table. You click on the "Seat" button to mark the table as seated.:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Restaurant',
      home: Column(children: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Table>( //Provider
          create: (_) => Table("Staff"),  //create controller
          child: Builder(builder: (context) {
            return Column(children: [
              Text("Staff seated: ${context.watch<Table>().seated}"),  //consume changes
              ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text("Seat Staff"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.read<Table>().toggleSeated();  //call controller
                  }),
            ]);
          }),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Table>(. //Provider
            create: (_) => Table("VIP"),  //create controller
            child: Builder(
              builder: (context) {
                return Column(children: [
                  Text("VIP seated: ${context.watch<Table>().seated}"),  //consume changes
                  ElevatedButton(
                      child: const Text("Seat VIP"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        context.read<Table>().toggleSeated();  //call controller
                      }),
                ]);
              },
            )),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

and associated narrowed down controller:

```
class Table extends ChangeNotifier {
  final String name;
  int chairs = 0;
  bool seated = false;

  Table(this.name);

  toggleSeated() {
    seated = !seated;
    notifyListeners();  //notify providers
  }
}
```

Now here is the `GetX` code (which compiles fine) but I tried `t.toggle` and `Get.find<Table>().toggle` and both functions toggle both tables at the same time. In the old code they toggled the tables individually:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Restaurant',
        home: Column(
          children: [
            GetBuilder(  //GetX
              init: Table("Staff"),  //create controller
              builder: (Table t) {
                return Column(children: [
                  Text("Staff seated: ${t.seated}"),  //consume changes
                  ElevatedButton(
                    child: const Text("Seat Staff"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      //I've tried Get.find here
                      Get.find<Table>().toggleSeated();  //call controller
                    },
                  ),
                ]);
              },
            ),
            GetBuilder(. //GetX
              init: Table("VIP"),  //create controller
              builder: (Table t) {
                return Column(children: [
                  Text("VIP seated: ${t.seated}"),  //consume changes
                  ElevatedButton(
                    child: const Text("Seat VIP"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      //I've also tried directly using the controller
                      t.toggleSeated();  //call controller
                    },
                  ),
                ]);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

and associated narrowed down controller:

```dart
class Table extends GetxController {
  final String name;
  int chairs = 0;
  bool seated = false;

  Table(this.name);

  toggleSeated() {
    seated = !seated;
    update();  //notify GetX
  }
}
```

In the `Provider` version I can interact with the tables individually but in the `GetX` version the button seems to act on all tables regardless of whether I use `Get.find<Table>()` or directly using the controller's `t.toggle`.

Comment: This is a really good question. I guess the reason would be the internal working here you are accessing only one instance simultaneously hence toggling all at once. I explored the tag property in getx for multiple instances but it isn't that dynamic, A mapping of booleans could be one solution. But I am still looking in the internal code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers are created per type, but you can add 'tag' to create separate controllers. Also you need to add the controller to Get to have proper lifecycle:
`Get.put(Table())`

Like you have 'Staff' and 'VIP' you can pass that as a tag:
`Get.put(Table(), tag: 'Staff')`

GetX Controllers automatically released when the caller disposed so in your case when you leave the given page.

You can find the 'Staff' Controller downstream with Get.find(tag:'Staff');

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an instance of Table just like package [example](https://pub.dev/packages/get/example). you can't directly use it on your screen.

```
Controller controller = Get.put(Table());
// ↑ declare controller inside build method
```

You can check [Baker's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65405741/how-to-flutter-getx-binds-obs-to-widget) answer too.

Comment: But what if I need to access it in another widget downstream?